# Как построить график преобразования Фурье

Tags: c++, math, transform, graph

Я пишу программу, работающую с преобразованием Фурье. Для преобразования я использую C++ библиотеку *fftw*. В общем, на вход отправляется массив вещественных чисел а на выходе получаю массив комплексных. Мне нужно построить график результата. Что мне делать с получившимися числами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Вариант 1

Построить два графика: вещественную и мнимую часть отдельно. `y(i) = Re(x[i])`, `y(i) = Im(x[i])`

### Вариант 2

Построить два графика: модуль и фазу отдельно. `y(i) = Abs(x[i])`, `y(i) = Arg(x[i])`

### Вариант 3

Построить график, где амплитудой точки будет являться модуль, а её цветом - фаза комплексного числа.

Comment: Либо в opengl карту высот и свободную камеру)

Comment: @vp_arth это скорее для непрерывного преобразования фурье. Или хотя бы для дискретного на сетке. А так получается одномерная сетка - мой **вариант 3**